# Nullpointerexception throws when inserting entity using Auto-generated Classendpoint insert method

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am confused to using auto-generated endpoint class. I want to use generated endpoint to insert new object into datastore. But, an exception is throwing.

```
fooEndpoint.insertFoo(foo); // throws null pointer exception
```

My entity class is similar with the given example at this source:  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jpa/overview.

Here is my entity:

```
@Entity
public class Foo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key ID;
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManager.find(JPAEntityManager.java:318)
at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManager.find(JPAEntityManager.java:256)
at com.FooEndpoint.containsFoo(FooEndpoint.java:150)
at com.FooEndpoint.insertFoo(FooEndpoint.java:96)
```

On the other side, I can insert new object when I use the EntityManager persist method. Because, this does not check exist or not on the datastore.

I expect that, classEndpoint insert method should save the object and assing auto key to ID field.

Or I need to initialize the ID field.

Here is auto-generated endpoint class insertFoo method.

```
  /**
 * This inserts a new entity into App Engine datastore. If the entity already
 * exists in the datastore, an exception is thrown.
 * It uses HTTP POST method.
 *
 * @param foo the entity to be inserted.
 * @return The inserted entity.
 */
public Foo insertFoo(Foo foo) {
    EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
    try {
        if (containsFoo(foo)) {
            throw new EntityExistsException("Object already exists");
        }
        mgr.persist(foo);
    } finally {
        mgr.close();
    }
    return foo;
}
```

Here is the containsFoo method

```
    private boolean containsFoo(Foo foo) {
    EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
    boolean contains = true;
    try {
        Foo item = mgr.find(Foo.class, foo.getID());  // exception occurs here
        if (item == null) {
            contains = false;
        }
    } finally {
        mgr.close();
    }
    return contains;
}
```

foo.getID() is null. Because, it is new object. I am expecting that, app engine creates a key for it. Or I need to explicitly create a key for it?

Other fields in Foo class are simple types such as String and booleans.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you provide the source for the `insertFoo` method? What are you passing as `foo`?

Comment: I realize that old version of the cloud endpoint generator insert method is different from the new version. Because, insert method at old version make persistent the object without existence check(contain method). But, the new ones check existence of the object. But, if the key is null, an exception is throwing. Please, is this case normal or not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem.
I will present the way I worked around it.

Original auto-generated Endpoints class relevant code:

```java
private boolean containsFoo(Foo foo) {
    EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager(); 
    boolean contains = true;
    try {
        Foo item = mgr.find(Foo.class, foo.getID());
        if (item == null) {
            contains = false;
        }
    } finally {
        mgr.close();
    }
    return contains;
}
```

Changed relevant code to include a null check for the entity object that is passed as an argument.

```java
private boolean containsFoo(Foo foo) {
    EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager(); 
    boolean contains = true;
    try {
        // If no ID was set, the entity doesn't exist yet.
        if(foo.getID() == null)
            return false;
        Foo item = mgr.find(Foo.class, foo.getID());
        if (item == null) {
            contains = false;
        }
    } finally {
        mgr.close();
    }
    return contains;
}
```

This way it will work as supposed, although I'm confident that more experienced answers and explanations will appear.

Comment: The containsFoo method makes use of the Entity Manager's find() method, which in the context of the original question takes a null ID and crashes, not even being able to tell if the datastore contains or not that entity. My question is: if new entities don't have an ID, how can they be checked for existence requiring a valid ID?

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same exact problem after using the Eclipse Plugin to autogenerate the cloud endpoints (by selecting "Google > Generate Cloud Endpoint Class").

Following your advice, I added:

if(foo.getID() == null) // replace foo with the name of your own object
            return false;

The problem was solved.

How is that Google hasn't updated the autogenerated code yet as this must be a highly recurring issue?

Thanks for the solution.