# GAE insertObject endpoint call returning 503 Service Unavailable when service is available

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, android-studio

Android Studio generated AppEngine and Endpoints, calling insertObject (insertTTEvent) returns a 503.  Odd since the other endpoint generated the same way works fine.  I can manually insert using Google console, and I can get the object I inserted, so the endpoints are available (not 503).

My thought at this point is that the endpoint model has a List, which the other endpoint model (which works) doesn't have.  Or maybe I'm not accessing the current version of AppEngine(?)...

here is INFO and ERROR notes from Endpoint Log from Google AppEngine dashboard

```
2014-02-04 18:50:28.907 /_ah/spi/sic.emo.apptt.TTEventEndpoint.insertTTEvent 500 9ms 0kb TT Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.15.0-rc (gzip) module=default version=1
75.166.94.168 - - [04/Feb/2014:18:50:28 -0800] "POST /_ah/spi/sic.emo.apptt.TTEventEndpoint.insertTTEvent HTTP/1.1" 500 117 - "TT Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.15.0-rc (gzip)" "research-petal-332.appspot.com" ms=9 cpu_ms=42 cpm_usd=0.000013 app_engine_release=1.8.9 instance=00c61b117c67fa09551203071b652fff2e29cddd
I 2014-02-04 18:50:28.904
com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod: cause={0}
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManager.find(JPAEntityManager.java:318)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManager.find(JPAEntityManager.java:256)
    at sic.emo.apptt.TTEventEndpoint.containsTTEvent(TTEventEndpoint.java:157)
    at sic.emo.apptt.TTEventEndpoint.insertTTEvent(TTEventEndpoint.java:101)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:45)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:339)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:163)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:121)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:188)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
E 2014-02-04 18:50:28.905
com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManager.find(JPAEntityManager.java:318)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManager.find(JPAEntityManager.java:256)
    at sic.emo.apptt.TTEventEndpoint.containsTTEvent(TTEventEndpoint.java:157)
    at sic.emo.apptt.TTEventEndpoint.insertTTEvent(TTEventEndpoint.java:101)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:45)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:339)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:163)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:121)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:188)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you will need to put a break point at the following line: 
`sic.emo.apptt.TTEventEndpoint.containsTTEvent(TTEventEndpoint.java:157)`

Most likely what is happening is that the generated code is trying to find an entity and since you are doing an insert and not passing in a value for the key (null , which is ok), the code is crashing.

I suggest you first confirm via debugging if that is the case and then put in an if statement to check first if the providing ID (key) is not null. Only then do you go for the findEntity.

Comment: In the project, there are several files similarly named Tteventendpoint.java and TTEventEndpoint.java that get generated. I put breakpoints in apptt-AppEngine/src/main/java/{package}/TTEventEndpoint.java and they don't get reached.  Also the line number refered to wasn't inside insertTTEvent so probably wrong code.  Which generated file is the relevant one? Looking...

Comment: Confused since the LOG info came from the server side (Google console) maybe the code path is through uploaded code run on the cloud.  How would the server know the code path in the phone ?

Comment: maybe ID is not getting set by this method of autogenerating ID : `public class TTEvent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long eventID;`  is autogeneration of IDs supported?  ...searching...

Comment: there's a clue here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15226793/nullpointerexception-throws-when-inserting-entity-using-auto-generated-classendp) nullpointerexception-throws-when-inserting-entity-using-auto-generated-classend   the ContainsTTEvent is looking for the TTevent in the datastore before it has an ID assigned.

Comment: So I rolled back the Model/endpoint code to eliminate the auto-generation of uniqueID, and I'm generating a unique name for the entity row using a concatenation of username + DateTime (as a string).  I'd rather use some server side generated unique ID but I'm not keen on debugging this whole affair with all the generated code etc.  Perhaps there's a performance hit for using strings as uniqueID (names), maybe Google does some hashing on their side.  If you have a short example of the GenerationType stuff that works I'd love to see it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may have not added your Endpoint class into web.xml file.
Based on Java servlet API your are using or Endpoint you need to define the class manually into web.xml like this:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>services</param-name>
            <param-value>
                com.kamalan.backend.registration.UserRegistrationEndpoint,
                com.kamalan.backend.RegistrationEndpoint,
                com.kamalan.backend.MessagingEndpoint
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
```